# How to manipulate multiple solutions to equations while keeping variable names?

Tags: equation-solving

relatively new to Mathematica, but couldn't find an answer online for how to do this more cleanly.

I am solving these equations in six variables that give me a number of solutions, which are given as a list of rules, e.g.,

```
solution = {{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 2, x5 -> 1, x6 -> 0}, 
 {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 1, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 1}, 
 {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 1, x5 -> 1, x6 -> 1}, 
 {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 2}}
```

My next step is I need to calculate $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6$ *for each of these solutions*, which are some (unchanging) linear combination of these values. I am currently doing this by defining (above everything), e.g.,

```
y1=x1-x3+x5
y2=x3+x4+x5
```

etc, and then running

```
xypairs = Table[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {x5, y5}, {x6, y6}} /. 
 solution[[j]], {j, 1, Length[solution]}]
```

which gives me a list of lists, where each sublist contains each of the xy pairs for that solution. However, for each of these solutions, I am trying to produce an expression that has 16 cases depending on the values of the xs and ys. When writing out these cases, I get things like

```
 xypairs[[t]][[2]][[2]] + xypairs[[t]][[4]][[2]] - xypairs[[t]][[3]][[2]]>=0 && xypairs[[t]][[2]][[2]]<0 && xypairs[[t]][[4]][[2]]<0
```

I feel there has to be a better way to do this, in that I want to be able to access a specific solutions xs and ys with fewer characters. If I were doing this in Python (where I am most comfortable), I would iterate through xypairs, and define variables for each of the x1,...,x6,y1,...,y6. This then allows me to manipulate xs and ys for the solution I am working with by using the variable name, instead of indexing. Please let me know what the best way to approach this is.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't iterate: that leads to messy expressions because you are forcing a working paradigm (procedural loops) onto a language that is not build for them. For instance, your xypairs could be obtained by `Transpose@{{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}} /. solution` without iterations. I suppose that the following step could probably be achieved with a similar approach, but you did not include enough information. The one thing I can say is that `xypairs[[t]][[2]][[2]]` should really be written `xypairs[[t, 2, 2]]`, if anything.

Comment: I'd also recommend *indexed* variables (e.g. `x[1]`) instead of explicitly named ones (like `x1`). It is then easier to construct lists of indexed variables for further manipulation. For instance, `Array[x, 6]` gives `{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6]}` etc.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you, this is all really helpful. It's been very clear to me that procedural loops aren't the best way to do this, I'm just looking for the best way. Essentially, if I were doing this in Python (where I am most comfortable), I would iterate through xypairs, and define variables for each of the x1,...,x6,y1,...,y6. This then allows me to manipulate the xs and ys I am working with by using the variable name, instead of indexing. Is this information helpful in terms of the best way to do the next step? I'll edit my question to add this info.

Comment: Lucas, I think we need a bit more info on the manipulations you want to do later, as well as the specific form of the $y_i$s. The best advice I can give you with the information you provided is: a loop-based iteration is unlikely to be the best approach in MMA. However, to figure out how exactly you could accomplish what you want, we need to know what you want to do in detail :-)

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the quick response. For each of the solutions, I am trying to create an expression dependent on many cases (~16) based on relations with  the xs and ys. For example, one case is y2+y4-y3>=0, x2>0, x3>0. Most cases are like that, involving 3+ inequalities with the xs and the ys. I have a huge Piecewise function, but when writing out the cases it just gets too messy. In my ideal world, I am able to write the cases as I did above, but where I am struggling is getting the xs and ys in a form where I can reference them with a small number of characters (e.g., x2).

Comment: I've updated my question a bit to add more detail on what I mention in my above comment. Thank you very much for the help, sorry that my question is not clear. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
solution = {{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 2, x5 -> 1, x6 -> 0}, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 1, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 1}, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 1, x5 -> 1, 
x6 -> 1}, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 2}};

{nsol, nx} = Dimensions[solution]; (* nsol is the total number of x solution sets, and nx is the total number of x variables in each set *)

x[i_, j_] := Values[solution][[i,j]] (* x values, where i is the x solution set number, and j is the x variable number  *)

xCoeff = {{1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}} ; (* Coefficients of the x variables in the y expressions, where the number of rows equals the number of y variables *)

{ny, nx} = Dimensions[xCoeff]; (* ny is the total number of y variables, and nx is the total number of x variables in each set *)

y[i_, j_] := Dot[xCoeff[[j]], x[i, All]] (* y values, where i is the x solution set number, and j is the y variable number  *)

xypairs[i_, j_] := Table[{x[n, m], y[n, m]}, {n, nsol}, {m, ny}][[i, j]](* list of x y pairs, where i is the x solution set number, and j is the y variable number  *)
```

CHECK RESULTS:

```
x[All, All]
```

Out: {{0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2}}

```
y[All, All]
```

Out: {{1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}.{{0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2}}

```
xypairs[All, All]
```

Out: {{{0, 1}, {0, 3}, {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 1}, {0, 3}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 2}, {1, -1}, {1, 2}, {0, -1}, {1, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}, {2, 1}}}